# Can a PDO $statement -> execute more than one parameter?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

It's the last piece of this that eludes me, I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what's missing.

The longer part of this code works just fine, it's the UPDATE portion (in the
 dis_adjust.php file) that's causing the grief.

In place of the hard coded number 13, it needs to accept the variable 'catID'.

The variable 'catID' initially filters for the number 1, and is then UPDATED to 5 when the "Rewarded" button is clicked.

Not sure if I'm explaining it correctly, or clearly...perhaps it's the sleep deprivation.

```html
dis_adjust.php

<?php
require 'dis_db.php';
$tag_h_id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = 'UPDATE `coh_items` SET `enabled`=5, `rewarded_at`= now()  WHERE `category_id`=13 AND `tag_h_id`=:id';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
if ($statement->execute([':id' => $tag_h_id])) {
header("Location: http://localhost/green/management/disbursements.php");
}

<?php
   require 'dis_db.php';
   
   $sql = 'SELECT
       coh_items.id,
       coh_items.tag_h_id,
       coh_vendors.name,
       coh_vendors.phone,
       coh_vendors.tax_number,
       coh_vendors.currency_code,
       coh_items.purchase_price,
       COUNT(tag_h_id) AS Reports,
       (
           purchase_price * COUNT(tag_h_id)
       ) AS Reward
   FROM
       coh_items
   INNER JOIN coh_vendors ON coh_items.tag_h_id = coh_vendors.id
   WHERE
       coh_items.enabled = 1 AND category_id = ?
   GROUP BY
       tag_h_id;';
    
   $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
   //$statement  ->bindParam(':category_id', $catID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute([$_POST['catID']]);
   $people = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Disbursement</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/green/vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!--    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
      <!-- <script src="http://localhost/green/vendor/almasaeed2010/adminlte/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script> -->
      <style type="text/css">
      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="page-header clearfix">
               <h3 class="center">Details by Category</h3>
               <div>
                  <!--Filter Button  -->
                  <div>
                     <div class="col-md-2">
                        <p class="margin"></p>
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <div class="input-group-btn">
                              <form action="http://localhost/green/management/disbursements.php" method="post">
                              <input type="text" name = "catID" placeholder="Category" class="form-control" >
                              <input type="submit" value= "Filter" class="btn btn-primary ">Filter</button></d>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <br>
               <br>
               <div class="col-md-8">
                  <table class="table table-bordered">
                     <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Zip</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Number of Reports</th>
                        <th>Award</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                     </tr>
                     <?php foreach($people as $person): ?>
                     <tr>
                        <td><?= $person->tag_h_id; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $person->name; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $person->phone; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $person->tax_number; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $person->currency_code; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $person->Reports; ?></td>
                        <td><?= $person->Reward; ?></td>
                        <td> 
                           <a  href="./disbursements/dis_adjust.php?id=<?= $person->tag_h_id ?>" name = 'adjust' class='btn btn-success'>Rewarded</a>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Use ? as a parameter in sql query and use execute($arrayOfParameter) method for execute query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) can accept an arbitrary number of parameters. To modify yours to use the variable `$catId`, change your query to:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `coh_items` SET `enabled`=5, `rewarded_at`= now()  WHERE `category_id`=:cat_id AND `tag_h_id`=:id';
```

and the `execute` call to:

```
$statement->execute([':id' => $tag_h_id, ':cat_id' => $catID])
```

Comment: G'day, thank you for responding so quickly, I really appreciate it.
Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue. I wonder if it's because the catID variable is being generated within another file?

Comment: @DaveZest What other file is it generated in? Is it not the `$_POST['catID']` you refer to later in the code?

Comment: That is correct...the entire script is listed just below the dis_adjust.php file.

Comment: Is that a separate file?

Comment: Yes, my apologies...(I'm a novice at this). Perhaps I ought to have put a line beneath the dis_adjust.php file, and titled the second portion dis_tabs3.php. The header("Location: ") refers to the main file that contains the dis_tabs3.php file.

Comment: Better to have had two separate code blocks. Then it's obvious they're different files. From looking further down, perhaps you can change `<a href="./disbursements/dis_adjust.php?id=<?= $person->tag_h_id ?>` to `<a href="./disbursements/dis_adjust.php?id=<?= "{$person->tag_h_id}&catID={$_POST['catID']}" ?>` and then you can access that value as `$_GET['catID']` in dis_adjust.php

Comment: So this is how I have the code now:
<?php
require 'dis_db.php';
$tag_h_id = $_GET['id'];
$cat_id = $_GET['catID'];
$sql = 'UPDATE coh_items SET enabled=5, rewarded_at= now()  WHERE  tag_h_id=:id AND category_id =:cat_id' ;
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([':id' => $tag_h_id, ':cat_id' => $catID]);
if ($statement) {
  header("Location: http://localhost/green/management/disbursements.php");
}
But it still doesn't update the table.

Comment: Is it redirecting correctly (i.e. `$statement` is not false?)?

Comment: Commenting out the header("Location: ") line, and clicking the Rewarded button the url window reads: http://localhost/green/management/disbursements/dis_adjust.php?id=1&catID=10
Which I think is correct, but the message reads: Notice: Undefined variable: catID in C:\xampp\htdocs\green\management\disbursements\dis_adjust.php on line 7

Comment: Oh yeah - looking at your code you have `$cat_id = $_GET['catID'];` instead of `$catID = $_GET['catID'];`

Comment: Okay, so one isn't supposed to say thank you...but they don't say anything about a HUGE sense of gratitude. It WORKS!!! Cheers mate!